# How to get Youtube to auto caption my videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

I've uploaded some portuguese videos on Youtube hoping that I can get auto-subtitles but Youtube still shows that cc is unavailable 2 days after the upload. How can I get it to work? The dialogue is quite clear in the videos.